# Javascript / ReactJS Objects not copying as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following code:

I am expecting staticData not to change when gridData does.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const CheckData = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Data From {props.ds}</h1>
      {props.items.map((row) => (
        <div key={row.recordid}>{row.companyname}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([
    {recordid: 1,companyname: "Devshare"},
    {recordid: 2,companyname: "Shufflebeat"},
    {recordid: 3,companyname: "Mita"}
  ]);

  const staticData = [...gridData];

  const changeValue = () => {
    let nd = gridData;
    nd[2]["companyname"] = "Superman";
    setGridData([...nd]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckData ds="gridData" items={gridData} />
      <CheckData ds="staticData" items={staticData} />
      <button style={{ marginTop: "50px" }} onClick={changeValue}>
        Change a value in gridData
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why does value in staticData change when gridData does?  I thought I made a copy of the object - not create an instance.

[Code SandBox Test Code Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shape-llf3j?file=/src/App.js:0-969)

Comment: Spread only shallow copies. If you have nested, complex data you'll need to copy your state deeply

Comment: If you want to do a deep clone, i have had a lot of success with lodash's `_.cloneDeep()`

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Comment: Even with a deep clone... On every render you construct `staticData` from what's in `gridData`.  Why would it ever be different than what's in `gridData`?

Comment: Fair enough but this is not a complex copy (or is it).  Why didn't `[...gridData]` make an effective copy rather than an instance?

Comment: @David staticData is suppose to be a "history" table allowing users to undo things.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment on the question:

> staticData is suppose to be a "history" table allowing users to undo things.

Then you're building it in the wrong place.  When you do this in the component:

```
const staticData = [...gridData];
```

Then *on every render* you re-build `staticData` based on the current values in `gridData`.  So when the `gridData` state is updated and the component re-renders, you build a new `staticData` with the new values.

If `staticData` is supposed to be unchanging hard-coded data, define it outside the component:

```
const staticData = [
  {recordid: 1,companyname: "Devshare"},
  {recordid: 2,companyname: "Shufflebeat"},
  {recordid: 3,companyname: "Mita"}
];
```

And then within the component use it as the initial state value for `gridData`:

```
export default function App() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState(staticData);

  //...
};
```

That way `staticData` is only defined once in the module.  `gridData` can be updated in state as many times as you like but that won't affect `staticData`.

Comment: Hard-coded data was used for simplicity - the data will be coming from an API call.

Comment: @Elcid_91: Alternatively you might track it in its own state value then.  Either way the main point is that you can't track two different sets of data in the same state, which is what the code in the question is currently trying to do.

Comment: David - so you are saying that when I clicked that button  and the re-render occurs, that `let staticState=[...gridData]` would be executed again?

Comment: @Elcid_91: Correct.  The component itself (in this case `App`) is a function and that function is executed on every render.

Comment: Makes total sense now.  Thanks!